# Measure actual time spent in python script

Tags: python, multiprocessing, operating-system

I want to measure the exact time python script takes when it runs on command line and exclude the time being spent in context switches and other OS related stuff.

**Problem:**
I am executing 50 instances of a python script in parallel using crond on 56 core machine. While one instance of python script takes around 2 second,  execution time of each script increases to 13 seconds when triggered in parallel.

**Rule Out:**
I want to rule out the time being spent in context switches and other OS related stuff.

**Note:**
There is no access to shared resource in the script

Answer (score -1):

I think the problem lies in the OS task scheduler and how the GIL works, which leads to the so-called convoy effect.

Note from from a great [article](https://tenthousandmeters.com/blog/python-behind-the-scenes-13-the-gil-and-its-effects-on-python-multithreading/#:%7E:text=The%20convoy%20effect%20takes,thread%20release%20the%20GIL.). I hope this article helps you

> The convoy effect takes place because each time the I/O-bound thread performs an I/O operation, it releases the GIL, and when it tries to reacquire the GIL after the operation, the GIL is likely to be already taken by the CPU-bound thread. So the I/O-bound thread must wait for at least 5 ms before it can set eval_breaker and gil_drop_request to force the CPU-bound thread release the GIL.

Comment: I checked this article and this talks about multiple threads whereas my problem is that even multiple processes are taking more time to execute